# getFrameAtTime: videoFrame is NULL pointer

Tags: java, android

It's my code . I want to get video thumbnail ，  I got thumbnail from .MP4 but I can't get thumbnail from .AVI ,I just got a blank pic , it's may a Android's BUG,I can't find the solution , have you ever met the same problem ? give me some help thanks !

```
private Bitmap getVideoThumbnail(String videoPath, int width, int height, int kind) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoPath, kind);
    bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap, width, height,
    ThumbnailUtils.OPTIONS_RECYCLE_INPUT);
    return bitmap;
}
```